# How can I see which (system) apps are installed with which account?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have three different Google accounts on my phone, with one the default one. I want all apps to be installed on that account. I've just noticed that one app was installed with an account that is not under my control. Strangely enough this is a system app.

How can I see which apps are installed with which account?

Comment: "one app was installed with an account that is not under my control." -> can you elaborate on this? If it is a system app, it would have already been installed in the phone before you got the phone. What is your reasoning for deducing that this particular app was "installed with an account that is not under my control"?

Comment: It's very simple, just like I said. The Google account is not under my control. It belongs to an organisation and they can decide to take over the account. It won't happen, but it's a possibility.

Comment: I think there may be a miscommunication. What I meant is, you observed something (A), then had a reasoning process (B) to deduce that "one app was installed with an account that is not under my control". Could you share about the A and B? Then we could try to answer more accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System apps come with OS before even adding accounts. They have nothing to do with which account you use.

Google accounts matter only for user installed apps either if it is a paid app or if auto backup is enabled for that app and you backup your apps.

Only exception I can think of is that your device is rooted and you installed an app that can be made into a system app, and you are now assuming that this system app is associated with Google account.

Comment: OK thanks. I see that for system apps it doesn't matter. However, in the past I've had my personal Whatsapp account linked to a work account. I discovered this just in time, could recover a backup and move it to my personal account. Now this happens, and it made me wonder how I can see which apps are linked to which account.

Comment: This ideally should be a separate question. I am not sure how to do this